# Is loop "for" prior to "if" statement in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to a programming language and wanted to start with Python as its the recommendation of most people (as far as i see).

So, im practising on some functions to improve my understanding on loops, and basic statements etc. Though i'm not very good at it yet, i do believe that i'll improve sooner or later.

Here is an example where i'm stuck at:

```
  def L():
    List = []
    TauS = []
    a = 12
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a % i == 0:
            List.append(i)

    if a % len(List) == 0:
        TauS.append(a)

    print(List)
    print(TauS)

L()
```

This is the function i want to have and the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
[12]
```

As i expected.However, the problem is that i want "a" to be a variable instead of a constant.Something like:

```
    def L():
        List = []
        TauS = []
        for a in range(2,20):
            for i in range(1,a+1):
                if a % i == 0:
                    List.append(i)

        if a % len(List) == 0:
            TauS.append(a)

    print(List)
    print(TauS)                                                         
 L()
```

Fails because it seems like for loop is working before the 2nd if statement (`if a % len(list)) == 0: TauS.append(a)`).I have also tried a "while" loop instead of a "for" loop as:

```
a = 2
while a <= 20:
    for i in range(1,a+1):...(The rest is the same)
```

It would be a better idea if your help focus on the basic ideas instead of just giving the right function.

Thanks a lot from now!

Regards.

Comment: Put the `if` inside the loop.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and give an example of the current and the expected output?

Comment: First and foremost, the variable `List` may conflict/confuse with the reserved `list` keyword in Python. Select a variable name that doesn't confuse/conflict with built-in keywords/functions/identifiers in Python. It could be as simple as `l`, but its best to have descriptive variable names such us `list_1`.

Comment: Hi again; My current output is: L = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 7, 1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 1, 13, 1, 2, 7, 14
, 1, 3, 5, 15, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 1, 17, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 1, 19] and TauS = [2, 2, 3, 3] which is not what i needed.My expected output is: L=[[1,2],[1,2,4,8],[1,3,9],[1,2,3,4,6,12],[1,2,3,6,9,18]] and TauS = [2,8,9,12,18].I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses indention levels to tell whether code is in within a function, loop or condition, the general thing being that if there is a `:` then all the code indented underneath it is within that statement.

The problem with your code is that the second if statement is on the same indention level as the for loop rather than being on the indention level below the for loop. This means that rather than running in the for loop it runs after it.

So to fix your code all you need to do is select the if statement and press `crtl + ]` which is pythons keyboard shortcut for indent code section.

edit:

I think what you're asking for is to get all the factors of numbers from 2 to 19 and then print numbers where the number of factors is a factor of that number.

```
def L(): 
    List = []
    TauS = []
    for a in range(2,20):
        l=[]  #this is the list for each individual number

        #if i is a factor of a add it to l
        for i in range(1,a+1):
            if a % i == 0:
                l.append(i)   

        #if length of l is a factor of a add a to TauS
        if a % len(l) == 0:  
            TauS.append(a)
            List.append(l)
    print(List)
    print(TauS)

L()
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the fast answer; but it doesn't solve my problem.I've tried almost any combinations without even logic :( Nothing gives me my expected answer.My current output is: L = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 7, 1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 9, 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 1, 13, 1, 2, 7, 14 , 1, 3, 5, 15, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 1, 17, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 1, 19] and TauS = [2, 2, 3, 3] which is not what i needed.My expected output is: L=[[1,2],[1,2,4,8],[1,3,9],[1,2,3,4,6,12],[1,2,3,6,9,18]] and TauS = [2,8,9,12,18].

Comment: What is this code trying to do? Get the factors of 2,8,9,12,18? because your current code print the factors of all numbers from 2 to 19 in one list.

Comment: That is called "Tau Numbers", (also called refactorable numbers) special numbers with the same properties. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactorable_number But i can't find a way for it yet.

Comment: Try the code in the edit, it should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

It fails because of variable scope.

Python uses indention to represent code block. So, here for loop and 2nd if condition has same indention which means they belong to same code block and can access variables defined in the same  or the outer code block. "List" & "Taus" in this case.

However, Variable "a" is localize to outer for loop and can be access in the same or inner for loop and cant be access from outside. Similarly variable "i" is specific to inner for loop and cant be access outside of the loops block, not even from outer for loop.

Hope it helps...